# ASP.NET 'Guest' Membership

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership

Is it possible to specify what is returned by `RoleProvider.GetRoles()` if a user is not logged in? I was thinking in case of a '`Guest`' user account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a [custom role provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx) and override the GetRolesForUser method to return a guest role if no username is passed.

Comment: I've tried that. If no username is provided the method doesn't even fire.

Comment: The problem is that I was calling System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser - instead of System.Web.Security.Roles.Provider.GetRolesForUser. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[`RolePrincipal.GetRoles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprincipal.getroles.aspx) needs to know who the user is in order to return the Roles it belongs to.

Comment: So then is there any way to add a 'Guest' role of some sort if there is nothing for it to lookup?